# What means about the `filterDatas`

Tags: java, http

In a book named “深入理解Java Web技术内幕”，have some code.

Its means is to create an HTTP request :

```
HttpClent httpClient = createHttpClient();
PostMethod postMethod;
String domainName = Switcher.domain;
postMethod = new PostMehtod(domainName);
postMethod.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form- urlencoded;charset=GBK");
for (FilterData filterData :filterDatas) {
    postMethod.addParameter("ip", filterData.ip);
    postMethod.addParameter("count", String.valueOf(filterData.count));
}
try {
    httpClient.executeMehtod(postMehtod);
    postmethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
} catch(Exception e){
    logger.error(e);
}
```

I know the struct of HTTP package. But don't know what means about `FilterData` on line #7.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is quite unclear as it is. I would advice to add more information, otherwise people will not be able to help you. Alternatively, maybe you can contact the author of the book?

Comment: If you're asking what `filterDatas` is, we're missing a bit of context on that code, as it isn't declared anywhere in your snippet.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think OP is wondering where `filterDatas` is defined? I assume it's an `Iterable<FilterData>`, but I do not see it referenced in the snippet.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yeah, I noticed, removed that comment and asked for a more pertinent clarification :)

Comment: I found the snippet of the book mentioned here https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_36952403/article/details/74910350, it's in Mandarin, in chrome you can get it translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `postMethod`'s type is [`org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod`](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html) - then you add just some parameters to it, using the two-parameter method `addParameter(String paramName, String paramValue)` which just `adds a new parameter to be used in the POST request body`.

I guess `FilterData` is some kind of generic class which just holds some values like `ip` and `count`. You're adding a parameter with the same name (`ip` and `count`) several times to the request, if `filterDatas` (which is an `FilterData[]` or any other kind of collection) contains more than one entry.

This is fine, according to Wikipedia:

> [...] This is a format for encoding key-value pairs with possibly duplicate
>   keys.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! When I saw the code and Wikipedia  from your answer . I understand about that. I used to suspect that it is just a normal parameter. but the `for` and `ip` confuze me. I don't understand why there may be multiple ip parameters. But now, maybe it’s just the author’s random action. Thanks again.

Comment: It's pretty unusual for me too, that's why I bothered to look it up. I wouldn't dare to say that this is unusual practice to send the same key multiple times, but I personally never did this. Also, the source is kind of incomplete since the class definitions of several classes are missing here :/ Have fun learning :)